# What is the shortcut key to search text in new Outlook email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Earlier, I was using shortcut key <kbd>F4</kbd> to search text in an email in Outlook from Office 365. It was working fine.

Recently, I got upgraded to new Outlook which was recently launched by Microsoft. However, I am unable to use text search function in an email. <kbd>F4</kbd> key no longer works. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key combination is used to forward the email.

So, how to search text in an email in new Outlook?

Comment: I can't even find that functionality in ribbon of new outlook, maybe it's not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If the traditional Ctrl+E or F3 don't work in the new Outlook,
one is left with the following.

The post [Search inside an email and search for emails (new Outlook)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/search-inside-an-email-and-search-for-emails-new/230f3cb9-0dd1-4b62-b942-506ad0f54f87)
has this answer from February 12, 2024, by user ckrf_work:

> I wrote to in-app support about this and got the following response
> (excerpted):
>
> *We regret to inform you that you are looking for in New Outlook is currently unavailable. However, we recognize that the feature is
> critical.*
>
> *We also have confirmation that our product development team is currently working on this feature. But currently there is no ETA as to
> when exactly the feature will be released and implemented on your
> device.*
>
> So fingers crossed!

This is left as the right answer, for the moment.

Comment: Agree with Harrymc, it's not available in New Outlook for Windows.